# Does performing an additional weightlifting set not increase progress by more than 5%?

Tags: medical-science, physical-fitness

Exrx, a widely-known exercise resource site, claims in its article [Low Volume Progressive Intensity Training](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/LowVolumeTraining.html):

> By performing an additional set (50% to 100% more sets) only 0 to 5% more progress will be observed. Each additional set yields even less progress to a point of diminishing return.

Is this statement supported by any research?

Comment: Looking for scientific research in the realm of lifting is usually a fool's errand. Methodology is so poor and the state of research so weak that the best approach is to try it yourself or ask someone with experience, as described by [Kurtis Frank](http://www.silverhydra.com/2012/03/empiricism-and-science-with-special-consideration-to-swole/).

Comment: However doing 0 sets returns a 0 to negative return.  So an additional set would seem yield infinitely more progress than doing no additional sets.  It also depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: @Chad If it's the first set, then it's not an additional set.

Comment: @Tim - I love how you split hairs of the wording instead of addressing the actual issue.  You are taking a single quote out of context and trying to apply it generically.  The quote deals with beginners trying to start out using routines of world class athletes.  It also only deals with strength training.  Bodybuilding is about more than strength.  Thus sometimes you exercise your muscles in different ways in order to get different effects.

Comment: @Chad -- You're the one creating the semantic argument here.

Answer (score 7):

Many of the low volume or high intensity styled programs make claims about diminishing returns from extra work. The easiest way to address this question is to look at the science of training volume. I agree with one of the commenter's (Dave) that exercise science is not always a solid science, but his recommendation replaces measurement with opinion.

Volume vs HIT: The Answer
There have been many studies that have sought to understand whether it is better to use a single set, many sets, how many sets, etc. Most of the training programs used by athletes today are based upon periodized programs developed by the former eastern block Olympic coaches. But there are two issues: strength and hypertrophy.

Firstly a [strength training meta-analysis by James Krieger](http://journals.lww.com/nsca-jscr/Abstract/2009/09000/Single_Versus_Multiple_Sets_of_Resistance.37.aspx) (Journal of Strength & Conditioning Research. 23(6):1890-1901, September 2009) found that 2-3 sets led to 46% greater strength gains than 1 set.

> There has been considerable debate over the optimal number of sets per
>   exercise to improve musculoskeletal strength during a resistance
>   exercise program. The purpose of this study was to use hierarchical,
>   random-effects meta-regression to compare the effects of single and
>   multiple sets per exercise on dynamic strength. English-language
>   studies comparing single with multiple sets per exercise, while
>   controlling for other variables, were considered eligible for
>   inclusion. The analysis comprised 92 effect sizes (ESs) nested within
>   30 treatment groups and 14 studies. Multiple sets were associated with
>   a larger ES than a single set (difference = 0.26 +/- 0.05; confidence
>   interval [CI]: 0.15, 0.37; p < 0.0001). In a dose-response model, 2 to
>   3 sets per exercise were associated with a significantly greater ES
>   than 1 set (difference = 0.25 +/- 0.06; CI: 0.14, 0.37; p = 0.0001).
>   There was no significant difference between 1 set per exercise and 4
>   to 6 sets per exercise (difference = 0.35 +/- 0.25; CI: -0.05, 0.74; p
>   = 0.17) or between 2 to 3 sets per exercise and 4 to 6 sets per exercise (difference = 0.09 +/- 0.20; CI: -0.31, 0.50; p = 0.64).
>   There were no interactions between set volume and training program
>   duration, subject training status, or whether the upper or lower body
>   was trained. Sensitivity analysis revealed no highly influential
>   studies, and no evidence of publication bias was observed. In
>   conclusion, 2 to 3 sets per exercise are associated with 46% greater
>   strength gains than 1 set, in both trained and untrained subjects.

Now the low volume claims are for diminishing returns after the first set. This is clearly not the case, but there is a point that no more strength is gained (4-6 sets) by performing more work. I won't address it here, but it is to do with how fast the body can restore ATP and how much micro-trauma has been induced.

Hypertrophy is the second part of weight training. [Krieger again performed a meta-analysis of the research](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20300012) (Journal of Strength and Conditioning Research: April 2010 - Volume 24 - Issue 4 - pp 1150-1159) and found that increasing the number of sets increased the amount of hypertrophy by 40% (up to 6 sets).

> Previous meta-analyses have compared the effects of single to multiple
>   sets on strength, but analyses on muscle hypertrophy are lacking. The
>   purpose of this study was to use multilevel meta-regression to compare
>   the effects of single and multiple sets per exercise on muscle
>   hypertrophy. The analysis comprised 55 effect sizes (ESs), nested
>   within 19 treatment groups and 8 studies. Multiple sets were
>   associated with a larger ES than a single set (difference = 0.10 Â±
>   0.04; confidence interval [CI]: 0.02, 0.19; p = 0.016). In a dose-response model, there was a trend for 2-3 sets per exercise to be
>   associated with a greater ES than 1 set (difference = 0.09 Â± 0.05;
>   CI: −0.02, 0.20; p = 0.09), and a trend for 4-6 sets per exercise to
>   be associated with a greater ES than 1 set (difference = 0.20 Â± 0.11;
>   CI: −0.04, 0.43; p = 0.096). Both of these trends were significant
>   when considering permutation test p values (p < 0.01). There was no
>   significant difference between 2-3 sets per exercise and 4-6 sets per
>   exercise (difference = 0.10 Â± 0.10; CI: −0.09, 0.30; p = 0.29). There
>   was a tendency for increasing ESs for an increasing number of sets
>   (0.24 for 1 set, 0.34 for 2-3 sets, and 0.44 for 4-6 sets).
>   Sensitivity analysis revealed no highly influential studies that
>   affected the magnitude of the observed differences, but one study did
>   slightly influence the level of significance and CI width. No evidence
>   of publication bias was observed. In conclusion, multiple sets are
>   associated with 40% greater hypertrophy-related ESs than 1 set, in
>   both trained and untrained subjects.

So there is no science to support the claim that doing more sets will only see small increases in returns. It is possible the person making this claim has not understood the conclusions of studies such as the ones I have cited, but it is more likely that the claims are unfounded.

Comment: Can you provide links to the papers?